# Does the Samsung Galaxy S Plus support moving applications to the SD card?

Tags: app2sd, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

On my Samsung Galaxy S phone, I cannot move applications to the SD card. It seems to be some configuration file error which you can only solve when rooting the phone.

Does anyone know if this has been fixed in it's successor, the Samsung Galaxy S Plus?

```
Model Number: GT-I9000
Firmware : 2.3.3
Baseband version: I9000XXJVO
Kernel version:  2.6.35.7
Build number: GINGERGREAD.XWJVH
```

Comment: What FW version do yo have?

Comment: @Flow Added the info in my question.

Answer (score 3):

What is the version of your OS in S1? If you are at least on Froyo, that should be doable for some applications. Note that not all can be moved to SD.

If you are on Eclair I believe you can't do this.

S Plus is on Gingerbread so it should work fine.